# How to insert input in a new cell with js

Tags: javascript

How can I insert an input in a new cell using js?

I try this but doesn't work.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('.option')
console.log(input)
//const id = ele.attributes.name.value
//console.dir(ele, id)

//Add row in table
const table = document.getElementById(id);
const indexRows = table.rows.length;
//console.log(table);

let newRow = table.insertRow(-1)
let newID = newRow.insertCell(0)
let newDesc = newRow.insertCell(1)
let newCell1 = newRow.insertCell(2)
//let newCell2 = newRow.insertCell(3)

newID.innerHTML = indexRows + 1
newDesc = input
```

Comment: Can you elaborate in regards to which lines specifically in the code you provided you feel should “*[insert] an [input]*” into the DOM?

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please [edit] and add relevant JS, HTML and CSS

Comment: Also `ele.attributes.name.value` does not seem like you are on the right track here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example. You've forgotten a lot of semicolons. Perhaps you also want to use `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML`.

```js
const table = document.getElementById("t");
const indexRows = table.rows.length;

let newRow = table.insertRow(-1);
let newID = newRow.insertCell(0);
let newDesc = newRow.insertCell(1);
let newCell1 = newRow.insertCell(2);

newID.innerHTML = indexRows + 3;
let input = document.createElement("input");
newDesc.appendChild(input);
newCell1.innerHTML = indexRows + 5;
```

```html
<table border=1 id="t">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: None of the semicolons are relevant

Comment: @mplungjan I didn't say that ;-)

Comment: You literally said: `You've forgotten a lot of semicolons.`

Comment: @mplungjan Yes but I didn't say they are relevant... ;-)

Comment: Perhaps say what IS relevant since neither textContent not semicolons were relevant to the issue